# how to get value of particular element when clicked on button which is having same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my html

```
<h3>IRCTC Checked Template</h3>
<div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here...IRCTC Checked Template</textarea>
<button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
 btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>

<h3>ID Created Template</h3>
<div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here... ID Created Template</textarea>
<button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
btnclass"  id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>
```

on click on the button which is having same class i want to get respective textarea value
here my javascript

```
$(".btnclass").click(function(){
alert($('.txt').val());
});
```

but the respective `.txt class` is not getting selected . for two buttons am getting same `.txt class` value. 
i want to get respective text class on cling on the button .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `.txt` elements. Instead you need to use DOM traversal to find the one related to the clicked `.btnclass` element. To do that you can use `prev()`, like this:

```js
$(".btnclass").click(function() {
  var value = $(this).prev('.txt').val();
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>IRCTC Checked Template</h3>
<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here...IRCTC Checked Template</textarea>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
 btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>

<h3>ID Created Template</h3>
<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here... ID Created Template</textarea>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>
```

To get all `.txt` values you can use `map()` to build an array of them:

```js
$(".btnclass").click(function() {
  var values = $('.txt').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>IRCTC Checked Template</h3>
<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here...IRCTC Checked Template</textarea>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
 btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>

<h3>ID Created Template</h3>
<div>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here... ID Created Template</textarea>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to get .txt class values on single click, would you help me? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: its getting only one txt class value on single click i want to get two txt values on single click.

Comment: Which two values do you want to get?

Comment: <textarea class='txt'> values

Comment: Please be clear - do you want all of them, or just two?

Comment: all of them which are having class as .txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.prev()` function :

```
$(".btnclass").click(function(){
  alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `$(this).parent().find('.txt')`. This will always select the `.txt` element inside the same parent as the pressed button.

```js
$(".w3-btn").click(function(){
alert($(this).parent().find('.txt').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here...IRCTC Checked Template</textarea>
<button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
 btnclass" id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>

<h3>ID Created Template</h3>
<div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" class="txt" form="usrform">
Enter text here... ID Created Template</textarea>
<button class="w3-btn w3-blue w3-border-black  w3-card-24 w3-hover-green 
btnclass"  id="btn" name="b">Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btnclass").click(function(){
   alert($(this).prev().val());
});
```